# Data migration transferring from old table into new table, with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, migration

Is it possible to copy data from old table into new table? We are planning a major database re-arrangement passing all datas to the current table to a newly created 
table.

We realized that it would be easy to handle the datas for newsfeeds and etc. here's my migration:

```
/*students table*/

    public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('lname');
                $table->string('mname')->nullable();
                $table->string('fname');
                $table->char('gender', 1);
                $table->date('date_of_birth');
                $table->string('address');
                $table->tinyInteger('yr_lvl');
                $table->string('contact_no');
                $table->text('about_me')->nullable();
                $table->text('education')->nullable();
                $table->text('achievements')->nullable();
                $table->text('seminars')->nullable();
                $table->text('organizations')->nullable();
                $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(1);
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }

    /*newly created table works*/
    Schema::create('works', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
                $table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('students')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->text('about_me')->nullable();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
```

Comment: You have 'old' table with different data structure and you need to transfer that data to a 'new' table (with different structure)?

Comment: no i just want to copy some data(about_me) to a new table... If u can see the other table(works) has a field about me and a foreign key from students

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my idea for you problem:

1) Create a migration file;

In that file in you up function:

2)create a object from your old table with selecting the required fields

Now

3) Write to migration code for the new table.

Now start a foreach loop  and store the data:

```
$oldData  = OLDTABLE::select('your_fields')->get();

Schema::create('works', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->increments('id');
                    $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
                    $table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('students')->onDelete('cascade');
                    $table->text('about_me')->nullable();
                    $table->timestamps();
                });

foreach ($oldData as $data){
  $newData = new Work();
  $newData->student_id = $data->student_id
  $newData->save();
}
```

4) run you migration